# Segmentation fault possible from code within false conditional block?

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault

I am interfacing with a USB audio codec in linux using the ALSA API. My code checks for either a `-r` or `-p` flag, and records or plays audio respectively:

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv){
   if(argc > 1){
     if(strcmp("-p", argv[1]) == 0){
       // Create data buffer, choose sampling rate
       char* playback_data;
       unsigned int sampling_rate = 44100;


       // Declare handle and params structure
       snd_pcm_t* handle;
       snd_pcm_hw_params_t* params;

       // Initiate and configure sound device
       init_playback_device(&handle, &params);
       config_playback_device(handle, params, sampling_rate);

       // Playback
       printf("playing...\n");
       playback(handle, params, playback_data, "test.raw", 3);

       // Close
       snd_pcm_hw_params_free(params);
       snd_pcm_close(handle);
       free(playback_data);

     } else if(strcmp("-r", argv[1]) == 0){
       // Create data buffer, choose sampling rate
       char* record_data;
       unsigned int sampling_rate = 44100;

       // Declare handle and params structure
       snd_pcm_t* handle;
       snd_pcm_hw_params_t* params;

       // Initiate and configure sound device
       init_recording_device(&handle, &params);
       config_recording_device(handle, params, sampling_rate);

       // Record
       printf("recording...\n");
       record(handle, params, record_data, "test.raw", 3);

       // Close
       snd_pcm_hw_params_free(params);
       snd_pcm_close(handle);
       free(record_data);
     }
   }
   return 0; 
 }
```

I am getting a segmentation fault whenever I run `./audio -r`. Oddly, when I comment out the code within the first if statement (`-p` flag), I don't get a segmentation fault. I don't understand why commenting out code that isn't running in the first place (due to the false conditional) yields a segfault. Using valgrind shows the following issues:

```
==22959== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==22959==    at 0x4848BAC: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==22959==    by 0x10DA7: main (audio.c:59)
==22959==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==22959==    at 0x10C5C: main (audio.c:14)
==22959==
==22959== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==22959==    at 0x4848BFC: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==22959==    by 0x10DA7: main (audio.c:59)
==22959==  Address 0x10b2c is in the Text segment of /home/pi/audio/audio
==22959==    at 0x10B2C: ??? (in /home/pi/audio/audio)
```

It does not like `free(record_data)` line since it believes `record_data` is uninitialized, however within my `record` function, i take care of this:

```
 void record(snd_pcm_t* handle, snd_pcm_hw_params_t* params, char* data_buffer, char file[], int duration){
   // Open file
   FILE* audio_file;
   audio_file = fopen(file, "w+");

   data_buffer = (char*) malloc(NUM_FRAMES * 4);

   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < (duration*10); i++){
     snd_pcm_readi(handle, data_buffer, NUM_FRAMES);
     fwrite(data_buffer, sizeof(char), NUM_FRAMES * 4 , audio_file);
   }

   fclose(audio_file);
 }
```

Where a pointer to `record_data` is passed as the parameter `data_buffer`. Anyone have any idea as to what is going wrong?

Edit:

The solution was to pass a pointer of `record_data`, since the `playback` function was issuing a pointer to a local variable:

```
 void record(snd_pcm_t* handle, snd_pcm_hw_params_t* params, char** data_buffer, char file[], int duration){
   // Open file
   FILE* audio_file;
   audio_file = fopen(file, "w+");
   *data_buffer = (char*) malloc(NUM_FRAMES * 4);
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < (duration*10); i++){
      snd_pcm_readi(handle, *data_buffer, NUM_FRAMES);
     fwrite(*data_buffer, sizeof(char), NUM_FRAMES * 4 , audio_file);
   }
   fclose(audio_file);
 }
```

I am still curious why commenting out the code in the first conditional block removed the error. Still unsure of why that was.

Comment: record_data is not initialize, you don't know where it is pointing to, so the call to record() with record_data's value as parameter is surely wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Valgrind is right. You are using an unitialized pointer. You need to allocate memory first, before writing to that location. While you do allocate memory inside your function, you only overwrite the *local* value of the pointer, but do not give that new pointer back to the surrounding code.

Compare where `record_data` points to before, inside, and after your function call.

Consider moving your `free` call inside of your record function, or returning the updated data pointer, or passing by reference. Either of these should fix most, if not all, of your issues.